# Is the Raft consensus algorithm a byzantine fault-tolerant (bft) algorithm?

Tags: distributed-computing, consensus, raft

Is the raft consensus algorithm a byzantine fault tolerant algorithm?

How many (percentage of) nodes are required to reach agreement/consensus?

Comment: How is this too broad? It's a yes or no question.

Comment: I would guess because it's not a single question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, Raft's initial description  (by Diego Ongaro and John Ousterhout [(1)](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf)) is **not** byzantine fault-tolerant.

Imagine a node that votes twice in a given term, or votes for another node that has a log which is not *up-to-date* like its own and that node becomes leader. Such behaviour could cause *split-brains* (case where two nodes believing themselves to be leader) or inconsistencies in the log.

Many other scenarios like sending fake but valid *heartbeat* messages are also examples that show Raft is not byzantine fault-tolerant.

However there are several papers where a byzantine fault-tolerant version of Raft is presented [(2)](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=byzantine%20fault%20tolerance%20Raft&btnG=).

---

To reach consensus Raft needs the **majority** of nodes to be alive - `> 50%`.

This means in order to tolerate `t` failures, there have still to be `t+1` nodes working correctly.

So `2t+1` nodes are needed to be **t-resilient**, which is the smallest amount of nodes needed to reach consensus in presence of **partial synchrony** [(3)](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=42283) with just tolerating omission failures.

Comment: Thanks! What are the full list of BFT algorithms? Paxos, PBFT, etc.

Comment: I just read that tangaroa is bft raft algorithm. Why do we need bft raft algorithm?

Comment: With bft raft, is scalability affected?

Comment: @NathanAw This should be asked as a new question and not discussed in a comment